# Как изменить exit code bash в присутствии -e опции?

Tags: bash

У меня есть скрипт на python, который постоянно выходит с exit code 42. Вопрос: как заменить exit code в bash на другой, при этом сохранив число для дальнейшей обработки?

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
my_script.py
```

Comment: 1. какой именно смысл вы вкладываете в слово «заменить»? 2. что это за строчку вы привели в вопросе?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Это строчка из моего bash скрипта, флаги -xe подразумевают что выполнение скрипта сразу же прекратится если будет ненулевой exit code, my_script.py возвращает 42, поэтому скрипт сразу же падает. Я хочу чтобы была возможность в bash скрипте заменить код возврата 42 на 0. Чтобы скрипт не падал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

раз вы используете опцию `-e` программы *bash*, то команда внутри скрипта, вернувашая ненулевой код возврата, прекратит дальнейшую интерпретацию вашего скрипта. чтобы игнорировать ненулевой код возврата, можно, например, воспользоваться оператором списка `||`:

```
команда-которая-может-вернуть-ошибку || команда-которая-выполнится-в-этом-случае
```

если `команда-которая-может-вернуть-ошибку` вернёт ненулевой код возврата, то будет выполнена `команда-которая-выполнится-в-этом-случае`, и если эта вторая команда вернёт нулевой код возврата, то интерпретация скрипта продолжится в «штатном режиме».

простейший пример для второй команды — это `:` (двоеточие, подробнее см. `$ help :`). она не делает ничего, и завершается с нулевым кодом возврата.

такая конструкция не приведёт к прекращению интерпретации при использовании опции `-e`, даже если первая из команд вернёт ненулевой код возврата:

```
команда-которая-может-вернуть-ошибку || :
```

---

так как вам требуется сохранить код возврата «проблемной» команды, самое логичное — в правой части оператора `||` выполнить присвоение кода возврата последней выполненной команды (сохраняется в переменной `$?`) какой-нибудь переменной (например, `$result`):

```
команда-которая-может-вернуть-ошибку || result=$?
```

оператор присвоения `result=$?` всегда выполяется успешно, потому интерпретация скрипта не будет прервана.

---

итого:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
result=0
my_script.py || result=$?
echo "код возврата проблемной команды: $result"
```

Answer (score 0):

В копилку.

В bash уже есть внутренняя переменная-массив хронящя статусы конвеера или одиночно ввполненной команды:

```
PIPESTATUS
```

промер:

```
~$ ls -la | grep emacs
 drwx------    3 u0_a207  u0_a207       4096 Sep  4 19:58 .emacs.d
~$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
 0 0
```

Ссылки

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-PIPESTATUS

Comment: `PIPESTATUS` может быть полезным, но не ясно как это на текущий вопрос отвечает. Если нашли что-то интересное («как статусы команд в конвейере получить в баше») и хотите поделиться с другими (или будущим собой), можете сами вопрос задать и ответить на него — [это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)